# Codeigniter - Url Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-url

i will make a project management web app. if the user register the system will give a URL.

> www.site.com/company_name

how should i do it when he user used this url it will also check in the database if it exist?

in codeigniter the format should be

> www.site.com/controller/function

Comment: What 'check in the database if it exist'?

Comment: yes sir if the company name is registered

Comment: can you spend 5 more minutes on the question to make it clearer. not within your mind words, use clear description.

Answer (score 3):

If this is about `Routing` then you may create a `Controller` i.e. `Profile` to retrieve the `user` according to `company_name` passed in to the `url`, in this case you may route it like

```
// application/config/routes.php
$route['(:any)'] = 'profile/get_user/$1';
```

In this case, when a `url` like `www.site.com/microsoft` is given, this will be routed to `Profile` controller and will call the `get_user` method and `microsoft` will be passed to the method as it's parameter. So, your controller should look something like this

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

    public function get_user($company_name = null)
    {
        // Check if $company_name exists or not and do something with it
        // Query for the user in the appropriate table
        // and search using $company_name (make sure this field is unique)
    }
}
```

Also, you can use a route like this

```
$route['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = "profile/get_user/$1";
```

Also, remember, a url with `www.site.com/john` could also be routed to `profile/get_user/john` instead of `User/show/john` if you have a controller/method like this. Read more on [URI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html).